# How to calcumate the seasonal sum by conditions with applying function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that has date, latitude, region, and count columns. Here are the steps to calculate the desired summation:

1. Subset the Dataframe into sub-summer Dataframes of different years based on `date`: 2019-06-01--2019-08-31, 2020-06-01--2020-08-31, 2021-06-01--2021-08-31
2. Split the dataframe by three `latitude` thresholds: 60-70, 70-80, 80-90.
3. Check the `region` value and multiply the `count` by a constant based on the `region` value: region=='land' -> *2; region=='ocean' -> *4; region=='coast' -> *8
4. Sum the `count`

Finally, I will get this dataframe with values are summations:

```
    |60-70|70-80|80-90|
2019|.    |.    |.    |
2020|.    |.    |.    |
2021|.    |.    |.    |
```

It seems I have to calculate each element like this:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2021-12-31', periods=360),
                   'latitude': np.linspace(50, 90, 360),
                   'region': ['land', 'ocean', 'coast'] * 120,
                   'count': [1, 2, 3] * 120,
                   })
df_test['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['date'])
df_test = df_test.set_index(['date'])

df_2019 = df_test['2019-06-01':'2019-08-31']
df_2019_60_70 = df_2019[(df_2019['latitude']>60)&(df_2019['latitude']<70)
df_2019_60_70_sum = df_2019_60_70[df_2019_60_70['region']=='land')]['count'].sum()*2
+ df_2019_60_70[df_2019_60_70['region']=='ocean')]['count'].sum()*4
+ df_2019_60_70[df_2019_60_70['region']=='coast')]['count'].sum()*8
```

And then save them into one Dataframe later. Is there any easier method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I find the answer by myself:

```
# multiple the constant first
df_test.loc[df_test.region == 'land', 'count'] *= 2
df_test.loc[df_test.region == 'ocean', 'count'] *= 4
df_test.loc[df_test.region == 'coast', 'count'] *= 8

# get the summer data
df_test_summer = df_test[df_test.index.month.isin([6,7,8])]

# groupby year and latitude bins, then sum
df_test_summer.groupby(by=[df_test_summer.index.year, pd.cut(df_test_summer.latitude,[60, 70, 80, 90])])['count'].sum().reset_index().pivot(index='date', columns='latitude', values='count')
```

[image: result]